# How to write a smart onblur event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

Lets imagine we have this sample code:

```
<input type="text" onblur="blurHandler()" />
<div class="results">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="clickHandler(this);">sampleText</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Lets say you have currently focus on your input tag, and you hover to the "a" tag and click it. The browser will handle the onblur event first.

The task of the blur event is that it should hide the results div, but you still want to be able to click the link in the results div before that happens.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a good solution if you had the div get hidden not on the input's blur event but e.g. on the results div's click event (plus optionally, say on document's click event if the user clicks outside). So the `clickHandler` would hide the results div as the last thing.

Comment: Do you want to keep the results-div open as long as the mouse is over it? Do you then want to close it on click, or keep it open?

Answer (score 1):

- In `blurHandler`, use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to delay hiding your div.

  ```
  function blurHandler() {
      setTimeout(function () {
          //close the div
      }, 100);
      //do whatever else needs to be done
  }
  ```

  [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b8H4z/)
- Another option would be to play with the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` events on the link, and use a common flag between the event handlers so that they know about each other.
- And one more: you can hide the div with a short animation, so it is actually still there when the click happens. Something like this:

  ```
   $('.results').hide(1000);
  ```

  [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b8H4z/1/)

---

**Note**: you should take a look at [advanced event handling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html), inline event handlers can really mess up your HTML quickly. Separation of concerns helps others and your future self. If you use jQuery (seeing the tags under your question), you should use jQuery's event handling methods, which use the advanced model already.

Comment: Well the problem with this it works sometimes, and sometimes not.... very weird... any like minimal timeout number?

Comment: @ZeDonDino I created a fiddle for you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Marcell's comment, though perhaps more from a usability perspective.

Assigning a timeout (as suggested by bažmegakapa) means you're choosing an arbitrary time limit that may or may not fire before the user has processed what they are supposed to do before that time limit is over. Unless your UI somehow makes it clear that they must react within a given time frame, this is likely to lead to frustrated users.

Even taking for granted that the users have had time to process the directions on screen, there's also transition time between moving from keyboard to mouse (or touch, where it's even worse as you have to deal with the UI shifting to hide the soft-keyboard), which means there's even more variance between different users' and their ability to follow the directions before the time limit you've chosen is over.

Just something to think about, in regard to how your interactivity is set up.